# External command visibility in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, shell-escape

How commands defined in my shell RC file (e.g. `.bashrc`) can be made visible to Texmaker?

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot shell {python -c 'print 0,0'};
\addplot shell {octave -q --eval 'disp([0 0])'};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

On my Linux machine, Python is available to all users, but GNU Octave is only added to the path later in my `.bashrc`. Both plots will work if I compile by hand:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex
```

If I try it within Texmaker, only Python is found.

Comment: Why don't you add the path for Octave to `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @egreg, I thought of it, will try it if no other solution is available. Actually, I'm just lazy to restart my computer. :)

Comment: @egreg, see my answer, the correct place to add the path is `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texmaker is probably calling Bash as `sh`, the consequence is that external commands defined in `~/.bashrc` aren't visible.

The correct place to set the environment is `~/.profile` (not `~/.bash_profile`).